# Maven. Deploy to glassfish with modules

Tags: maven, glassfish

Good day.

I use 'mvn clear package glassfish:deploy' from cmd for deploy. It's ok for app that includes only project. But with child modules i have some troubles with deploy.

This command gives me this error:

[Error] remote failure: File not found : [here project path]\target\test2.war

[Error] Deployment of [here project path]\target\test2.war failed

How to fix this?

Parent pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test.net</groupId>
  <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
  </modules>
  <name>test2 Maven Webapp</name>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                <glassfishDirectory>${local.glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
                    <user>admin</user>
                    <passwordFile>${local.glassfish.passfile}</passwordFile>
                    <domain>
                        <name>domain1</name>
                        <httpPort>8080</httpPort>
                        <adminPort>4848</adminPort>
                    </domain>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                            <artifact>target/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <terse>false</terse>
                    <echo>true</echo>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <finalName>test2</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

Child1 pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
    <groupId>test.net</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>child1 Maven Webapp</name>

  <properties>
    <deploy.glassfish>true</deploy.glassfish>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>child1</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Child2 pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
    <groupId>test.net</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>child2</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>child2 Maven Webapp</name>

  <properties>
    <deploy.glassfish>true</deploy.glassfish>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>child2</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with  below code in your parent pom.xml

```
<components>
    <component>
       <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
       <artifact>target/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
    </component>
</components>
```

Your parent pom is basically producing an artifact with type **pom**.
The `<artifact>target/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>` is trying to deploy a file with the name test2.war because `${project.build.finalName}.war` to the string "test2.war". But test2.war is not present in the target directory. The file that is present in the target directory is test2.pom. Hence you are getting the error.
There can be two ways for deploying your artifacts.

**The first approach:** If you want to deploy the child modules from within the parent modules then you need to have the below code for the glashfish plugin in your parent pom.

```
<components>
    <component>
       <artifact>path-to-your-child1-module</artifact>    // something like ../child1/target/child1.war
    </component>
    <component>
       <artifact>path-to-your-child2-module</artifact>    // something like ../child2/target/child2.war
    </component>
</components>
```

**The second approach** (which i think is better) would be to move your maven glassfish plugin from the parent module to the child module.
Replace the maven glassfish plugin code in your child poms with the one shown below.
For child1 pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <glassfishDirectory>${local.glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
                <user>admin</user>
                <passwordFile>${local.glassfish.passfile}</passwordFile>
                <domain>
                    <name>domain1</name>
                    <httpPort>8080</httpPort>
                    <adminPort>4848</adminPort>
                </domain>
                <components>
                    <component>
                        <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                        <artifact>target/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
                    </component>
                </components>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <terse>false</terse>
                <echo>true</echo>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <finalName>child1</finalName>
</build>
```

For child 2 pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <glassfishDirectory>${local.glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
                <user>admin</user>
                <passwordFile>${local.glassfish.passfile}</passwordFile>
                <domain>
                    <name>domain1</name>
                    <httpPort>8080</httpPort>
                    <adminPort>4848</adminPort>
                </domain>
                <components>
                    <component>
                        <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                        <artifact>target/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
                    </component>
                </components>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <terse>false</terse>
                <echo>true</echo>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <finalName>child2</finalName>
</build>
```

Don't forget to remove the maven glassfish plugin code from your parent pom.

Comment: Thanks you for answer. But for deploy using second approach deploy command should be executed separated for each child? Cause on executing it in parent pom i have error that 'glassfish' is incorrect prefix

Comment: For the second approach, You don't have to specify the deploy command. Try using the command `mvn clean install` at the parent pom level. This is because the deployment related stuff will be taken care by the plugin code in your poms. Also, you don't have to use the deploy command separately for each module. Your parent pom will trigger the child poms one by one which will deploy the child artifacts. Try the above command and let me know.

Comment: It's successfully compiled, child modules contains folders 'target' now. But without deploy to glassfish

Comment: Try using `mvn clean install glassfish:deploy`

Comment: Plugin with prefix 'glassfish' not found

Comment: I have added one more answer. Basically, the idea is to move the plugin code inside the `<pluginManagement>` tag in your parent pom. And reference this plugin from within your child pom.

Comment: And now again "not found .../test2.war"

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the glassfish-maven-plugin under build -> pluginManagement under your parent pom:

```
<pluginManagement>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <glassfishDirectory>${local.glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
                <user>${local.glassfish.user}</user>
                <passwordFile>${local.glassfish.passfile}</passwordFile>
                <domain>
                    <name>${local.glassfish.domain}</name>
                    <httpPort>${local.glassfish.httpport}</httpPort>
                    <adminPort>${local.glassfish.adminport}</adminPort>
                </domain>
                <components>
                    <component>
                        <name>${project.name}</name>
                        <artifact>target/${project.name}-${project.version}.war</artifact>
                    </component>
                </components>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <terse>false</terse>
                <echo>true</echo>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Then inside each of your child poms, add this plugin invocation:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```